# Are there Anti-Theft apps for iPad similar to cerberus for Android

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation

I have been looking for some anti-theft applications for iPad, like the wonderful [Cerberus application for Android](https://www.cerberusapp.com/) which enables a lot of features to recover your lost or stolen Android mobile for only 2/3€. Avast anti-theft also worked perfectly in my Android phone and its free.

I would like to know if you have tested any of them in you Apple device and could give me a hint before buying it. It will be a plus if it could detect if the 3G microSIM card is removed, and send an SMS to another mobile like Avast anti-theft application for Android does.

I don't mind about price, the more features the better.

I would like the following options:

- Remote control of the lost/stolen device (get SMS, get files, capture screen, turn on camera..)
- Possible remote control by sending SMS.
- Check for location of stolen device via remote turning on GPS or using 3G or any other method.

Comment: What features specifically are you looking for? We do not all know Cerberus very well. Have you looked into Find My iPad?

Comment: This is the best Anti-Theft app available for iOS devices. http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/find-my-iphone.html All the other ones are sandboxed, and likely won't have the options this does.

Comment: Added the specifications in my post. Just checked find my iphone app and seems really nice. I will test it, thank you so much.
By the way, dont know why my question was voted down. It was clear and I just wanted to know some opinions about anti-theft apps for ipad.

Comment: Perhaps it was voted down because Find My iPhone(iPad) is a well-known part of the Apple ecosystem, and you didn't mention it to begin with. If you had used it already, found it lacking in some way, then asked about other solutions, it would probably have a positive vote count. (Note: I didn't vote it down.)

Comment: I originally voted down because you did not add any specifications as for what features you were looking for, just a reference to an Android app I assume most in this community are not familiar with. Your question is much better now you added some specifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple makes their own anti-theft app, and it seems to be a fairly reasonable app as far as features. You can find out more about it [here](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/find-my-iphone.html).

As of iOS 6, and the latest version you can use it to *remotely* (among other things):

- Lock your device
- Erase your device (the app doesn't work after this)
- Display a message to the user
- Play a sound
- Geolocate the device
- Get directions to the device
- Put it in Lost mode, and allow the finder to call you while the device is locked (iPhone only)

Note that it has to have a internet connection, in order to communicate with whatever you are looking it up with. Also, it must have GPS for an accurate location - although wifi only devices that are connected to wifi should display their location, but it will be more general.

This app is the best one for iOS devices. Others have the limitation of sandboxing that Apple uses for security reasons. But sandboxing limits the features other anti-theft (it should be called "Recovery") apps can have.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer bassplayer7, I had played with a lot of security android apps but not too much with ios ones, this clears things up hehe.

Comment: Your welcome. Happy to help. Find my iPhone is really handy when someone just misplaces the devices too. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Prey is another good one. It works for all of your devices, not just iOS or Android. There is a three device limit for the free account. When you report the device as being lost or stolen, you can initiate tracking. This will send you back reports, IPs, screenshots, gps data, pictures from front facing cameras, etc. I can't tell you how great it works because fortunately none of my stuff has been stolen since I've used it, but it's nice to have another layer of security to fall back on in the event my devices end up in the wrong hands. http://preyproject.com/

Answer (score 2):

iCaughtU Pro. Takes a photo and GPS fix, then emails/SMS them to you when password is entered incorrectly. Also disables power button when locked, and will SMS if the SIM card is changed. Also has a "fake unlock" mode that allows access to only the apps you choose, and a remote control API via SMS/iMessage.

Answer (score 0):

[Lookout Mobile Security](https://www.lookout.com/iphone) which originally was developed only for Android is now available for iOS. Lookout for iOS gives you peace of mind that your device — and everything on it — is safe and secure.

Answer (score -1):

There is a new application name iAntiTheft, which help you to protect you phone when theft try to steal your phone.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iantitheft/id1026601065?mt=8

Basically it has some features.

- Power: Alarm when lightning cable is un-plugged.
- Motion: Alarm when device is moved.
- Pocket: Alarm when phone is picked out from pocket.
- Earpod: Alarm when ear-phone is un-plugged.
- Noise: Alarm when device hears a noise.

You could read it more on the iTunes link. Even it does not suitable to your requirement, but it might help you to protect your phone, save your money.